# RouteXL API clear tour

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Simple question here but I can't seem to find the answer... I have a google script interacting with the RouteXL API which has successfully managed it's first 'tour' test (thanks Spencer Easton and RouteXL).  However, now when I change the locations I get the return of 'Another route in progress' (error 429).  How do I clear the current route?

Comment: @SpencerEaston you might be able to help here

Answer (score 1):

Each account can only optimize one route at a time. If you fire a new tour request while the previous did not finish yet, the 429 error is thrown.

There is no call to clear the current route in progress. You'll have to wait until the route optimization algorithm finishes before sending the next.